# How do I redirect to another webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

How can I redirect the user from one page to another using jQuery or pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 16299, accepted):

### One does not simply redirect using jQuery

jQuery is not necessary, and [**`window.location.replace(...)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) will best simulate an HTTP redirect.

`window.location.replace(...)` is better than using `window.location.href`, because `replace()` does not keep the originating page in the session history, meaning the user won't get stuck in a never-ending back-button fiasco.

If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use
**`location.href`**

If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use
**`location.replace`**

**For example:**

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: Note: Similar behaviour to HTTP redirect for `replace()` means it won't create an entry in your browser's history.

Comment: If you display a page *only* to make a redirect, `location.replace()` will probably be more appropriate (exclude the page with a redirect from history). But why don't you do the redirect on the server side in the first place?

Comment: If anyone still has a problem that all the great answers you've applied but page redirect is not working then please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759020/window-location-href-doesnt-redirect

it works for my case.

Comment: @x-yuri my use-case is that URI fragments (after the # symbol) are not preserved via a server-side redirect because they're not sent to the server.

Comment: @bart Some kind of framework where a hash immediately follows the domain (`https://example.com/#some/path`)? Also, what's the difference between opening another page and a redirect? In my view, redirect implies something wanting to show page B instead of page A. If that something is not on the server, then why not just show the page B right away, why the redirect?

Comment: @x-yuri in my case, I moved the service that served those URLs with the URI fragments, and wanted old hyperlinks that people may have bookmarked to continue to work by redirecting them to the new site and preserving the fragment. You're right that the framework uses fragments instead of query parameters for some reason.

Comment: you probably meant 'one simply does not'

Answer (score 1834):

**WARNING:** This answer has merely been provided as a possible solution; it is obviously *not* the best solution, as it requires jQuery. Instead, prefer the pure JavaScript solution.

```js
$(location).prop('href', 'http://stackoverflow.com')
```

Answer (score 835):

## Standard "vanilla" JavaScript way to redirect a page

```
window.location.href = 'newPage.html';
```

### Or more simply:  (since `window` is Global)

```
location.href = 'newPage.html';
```

---

> **If you are here because you are *losing* HTTP_REFERER when redirecting, keep reading:**
>
> (Otherwise ignore this last part)

---

The following section is for those using `HTTP_REFERER` as one of many security measures (although it isn't a great protective measure). If you're using [Internet Explorer 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) or lower, these variables get lost when using any form of JavaScript page redirection (location.href,  etc.).

Below we are going to implement an alternative for **IE8 & lower** so that we don't lose HTTP_REFERER. Otherwise, you can almost always simply use `window.location.href`.

Testing against `HTTP_REFERER` (URL pasting, session, etc.) *can* help tell whether a request is legitimate.
*(**Note:** there are also ways to work-around / spoof these referrers, as noted by droop's link in the comments)*

---

Simple cross-browser testing solution (fallback to window.location.href for Internet Explorer 9+ and all other browsers)

**Usage: `redirect('anotherpage.aspx');`**

```
function redirect (url) {
    var ua        = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
        isIE      = ua.indexOf('msie') !== -1,
        version   = parseInt(ua.substr(4, 2), 10);

    // Internet Explorer 8 and lower
    if (isIE && version < 9) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
    }

    // All other browsers can use the standard window.location.href (they don't lose HTTP_REFERER like Internet Explorer 8 & lower does)
    else { 
        window.location.href = url; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 507):

There are lots of ways of doing this.

```
// window.location
window.location.replace('http://www.example.com')
window.location.assign('http://www.example.com')
window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'
document.location.href = '/path'

// window.history
window.history.back()
window.history.go(-1)

// window.navigate; ONLY for old versions of Internet Explorer
window.navigate('top.jsp')


// Probably no bueno
self.location = 'http://www.example.com';
top.location = 'http://www.example.com';

// jQuery
$(location).attr('href','http://www.example.com')
$(window).attr('location','http://www.example.com')
$(location).prop('href', 'http://www.example.com')
```

Comment: Related: [535 ways to reload the page with JavaScript](https://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html)

Answer (score 370):

This works for every browser:

```
window.location.href = 'your_url';
```

Answer (score 321):

It would help if you were a little more descriptive in what you are trying to do.  If you are trying to generate paged data, there are some options in how you do this.  You can generate separate links for each page that you want to be able to get directly to.

```
<a href='/path-to-page?page=1' class='pager-link'>1</a>
<a href='/path-to-page?page=2' class='pager-link'>2</a>
<span class='pager-link current-page'>3</a>
...
```

Note that the current page in the example is handled differently in the code and with CSS.

If you want the paged data to be changed via AJAX, this is where jQuery would come in.  What you would do is add a click handler to each of the anchor tags corresponding to a different page.  This click handler would invoke some jQuery code that goes and fetches the next page via AJAX and updates the table with the new data.  The example below assumes that you have a web service that returns the new page data.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('a.pager-link').click( function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href').split(/\?/)[1];
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/path-to-service',
            data: page,
            success: function(content) {
               $('#myTable').html(content);  // replace
            }
        });
        return false; // to stop link
    });
});
```

Answer (score 275):

I also think that `location.replace(URL)` is the best way, but if you want to notify the search engines about your redirection (they don't analyze JavaScript code to see the redirection) you should add the `rel="canonical"` meta tag to your website.

Adding a noscript section with a HTML refresh meta tag in it, is also a good solution. I suggest you to use this [JavaScript redirection tool](http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/) to create redirections. It also has Internet Explorer support to pass the HTTP referrer.

Sample code without delay looks like this:

```html
    <!-- Place this snippet right after opening the head tag to make it work properly -->

    <!-- This code is licensed under GNU GPL v3 -->
    <!-- You are allowed to freely copy, distribute and use this code, but removing author credit is strictly prohibited -->
    <!-- Generated by http://insider.zone/tools/client-side-url-redirect-generator/ -->

    <!-- REDIRECTING STARTS -->
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://yourdomain.example/"/>
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://yourdomain.example/">
    </noscript>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript">var IE_fix=true;</script><![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = "https://yourdomain.example/";
        if(typeof IE_fix != "undefined") // IE8 and lower fix to pass the http referer
        {
            document.write("redirecting..."); // Don't remove this line or appendChild() will fail because it is called before document.onload to make the redirect as fast as possible. Nobody will see this text, it is only a tech fix.
            var referLink = document.createElement("a");
            referLink.href = url;
            document.body.appendChild(referLink);
            referLink.click();
        }
        else { window.location.replace(url); } // All other browsers
    </script>
    <!-- Credit goes to http://insider.zone/ -->
    <!-- REDIRECTING ENDS -->
```

Comment: This is no longer true re: Search Engines not analyzing Javascript

Comment: Website used insider.zone is not live anymore it seems ( https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/insider.zone )

Answer (score 240):

But if someone wants to redirect back to home page then he may use the following snippet.

```
window.location = window.location.host
```

It would be helpful if you have three different environments as development, staging, and production.

You can explore this window or window.location object by just putting these words in Chrome Console or [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29)'s Console.

Answer (score 226):

JavaScript provides you many methods to retrieve and change the current URL which is displayed in browser's address bar. All these methods uses the Location object, which is  a property of the Window object. You can create a new Location object that has the current URL as follows..

```
var currentLocation = window.location;
```

**Basic Structure of a URL**

```
<protocol>//<hostname>:<port>/<pathname><search><hash>
```

[image]

1. Protocol -- Specifies the protocol name be used to access the resource on the Internet. (HTTP (without SSL) or HTTPS (with SSL))
2. hostname -- Host name specifies the host that owns the resource. For example, www.stackoverflow.com. A server provides services using the name of the host.
3. port -- A port number used to recognize a specific process to which an Internet or other network message is to be forwarded when it arrives at a server.
4. pathname -- The path gives info about the specific resource within the host that the Web client wants to access. For example, stackoverflow.com/index.html.
5. query --  A query string follows the path component, and provides a string of information that the resource can utilize for some purpose (for example, as parameters for a search or as data to be processed).
6. hash -- The anchor portion of a URL, includes the hash sign (#).

With these Location object properties you can access all of these URL components

1. **hash**   -Sets or returns the anchor portion of a URL.
2. **host**   -Sets
   or returns the hostname and port of a URL.
3. **hostname**   -Sets or
   returns the hostname of a URL.
4. **href**   -Sets or returns the entire
   URL.
5. **pathname**   -Sets or returns the path name of a URL.
6. **port** -Sets or returns the port number the server uses for a URL.
7. **protocol**   -Sets or returns the protocol of a URL.
8. **search**   -Sets
   or returns the query portion of a URL

Now If you want to change a page or redirect the user to some other page you can use the `href` property of the Location object like this

You can use the href property of the Location object.

```
window.location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

**Location Object** also have these three methods

1. **assign()** -- Loads a new document.
2. **reload()** -- Reloads the current document.
3. **replace()** -- Replaces the current document with a new one

You can use assign() and replace methods also to redirect to other pages like these

```
location.assign("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

location.replace("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

***How assign() and replace() differs*** -- The difference between replace() method and assign() method(), is that replace() removes the URL of the current document from the document history, means it is not possible to use the "back" button to navigate back to the original document. So Use the assign() method if you want to load a new document, andwant to give the option to navigate back to the original document.

You can change the location object href property using **jQuery** also  like this

```
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

And hence you can redirect the user to some other url.

Answer (score 217):

Basically **jQuery** is just a **JavaScript** framework and for doing some of the things like **redirection** in this case, you can just use pure JavaScript, so in that case you have 3 options using vanilla JavaScript:

1) Using location **replace**, this will replace the current history of the page, means that it is not possible to use the **back** button to go back to the original page.

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

2) Using location **assign**, this will keep the history for you and with using back button, you can go back to the original page:

```
window.location.assign("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

3) I recommend using one of those previous ways, but this could be the third option using pure JavaScript:

```
window.location.href="http://stackoverflow.com";
```

You can also write a function in jQuery to handle it, but not recommended as it's only one line pure JavaScript function, also you can use all of above functions without window if you are already in the window scope, for example `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");` could be `location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");`

Also I show them all on the image below:

[image: location.replace location.assign]

Answer (score 202):

Should just be able to set using `window.location`.

**Example:**

```
window.location = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
```

Here is a past post on the subject: [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 187):

**Before I start, jQuery is a JavaScript library used for DOM manipulation. So you should not be using jQuery for a page redirect.**

A quote from Jquery.com:

> While jQuery might run without major issues in older browser versions,
> we do not actively test jQuery in them and generally do not fix bugs
> that may appear in them.

It was found here:
https://jquery.com/browser-support/

So jQuery is not an end-all and be-all solution for backwards compatibility.

The following solution using raw JavaScript works in all browsers and have been standard for a long time so you don't need any libraries for cross browser support.

This page will redirect to **[Google](http://www.google.com)** after 3000 milliseconds

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>You will be redirected to google shortly.</p>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href="http://www.google.com"; // The URL that will be redirected too.
            }, 3000); // The bigger the number the longer the delay.
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Different options are as follows:

```
window.location.href="url"; // Simulates normal navigation to a new page
window.location.replace("url"); // Removes current URL from history and replaces it with a new URL
window.location.assign("url"); // Adds new URL to the history stack and redirects to the new URL

window.history.back(); // Simulates a back button click
window.history.go(-1); // Simulates a back button click
window.history.back(-1); // Simulates a back button click
window.navigate("page.html"); // Same as window.location="url"
```

When using replace, the back button will not go back to the redirect page, as if it was never in the history. If you want the user to be able to go back to the redirect page then use `window.location.href` or `window.location.assign`. If you do use an option that lets the user go back to the redirect page, remember that when you enter the redirect page it will redirect you back. So put that into consideration when picking an option for your redirect. Under conditions where the page is only redirecting when an action is done by the user then having the page in the back button history will be okay. But if the page auto redirects then you should use replace so that the user can use the back button without getting forced back to the page the redirect sends.

You can also use meta data to run a page redirect as followed.

**META Refresh**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://evil.example/" />
```

**META Location**

```
<meta http-equiv="location" content="URL=http://evil.example" />
```

**BASE Hijacking**

```
<base href="http://evil.example/" />
```

Many more methods to redirect your unsuspecting client to a page they may not wish to go can be found on this page (not one of them is reliant on jQuery):

> https://code.google.com/p/html5security/wiki/RedirectionMethods

I would also like to point out, people don't like to be randomly redirected. Only redirect people when absolutely needed. If you start redirecting people randomly they will never go to your site again.

The next paragraph is hypothetical:

You also may get reported as a malicious site. If that happens then when people click on a link to your site the users browser may warn them that your site is malicious. What may also happen is search engines may start dropping your rating if people are reporting a bad experience on your site.

Please review Google Webmaster Guidelines about redirects:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2721217?hl=en&ref_topic=6001971

Here is a fun little page that kicks you out of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Go Away</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Go Away</h1>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.history.back();
            }, 3000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you combine the two page examples together you would have an infant loop of rerouting that will guarantee that your user will never want to use your site ever again.

Answer (score 175):

```
var url = 'asdf.html';
window.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 151):

You can do that without jQuery as:

```
window.location = "http://yourdomain.com";
```

And if you want only jQuery then you can do it like:

```
$jq(window).attr("location","http://yourdomain.com");
```

Answer (score 149):

This works with jQuery:

```
$(window).attr("location", "http://google.fr");
```

Answer (score 101):

**# HTML Page Redirect Using jQuery/JavaScript Method**

Try this example code:

```
function YourJavaScriptFunction()
{
    var i = $('#login').val();
    if (i == 'login')
        window.location = "Login.php";
    else
        window.location = "Logout.php";
}
```

If you want to give a complete URL as **`window.location = "www.google.co.in";`**.

Answer (score 90):

**Original question:** "How to redirect using jQuery?", hence the answer implements jQuery >> Complimentary usage case.

---

To just redirect to a page with JavaScript:

```
window.location.href = "/contact/";
```

Or if you need a delay:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  window.location.href = "/contact/";
}, 2000);   // Time in milliseconds
```

jQuery allows you to select elements from a web page with ease. You can find anything you want on a page and then use jQuery to add special effects, react to user actions, or show and hide content inside or outside the element you have selected. All these tasks start with knowing [how to select an element or an event](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/).

```
$('a,img').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 0 //Put some CSS animation here
  }, 500);
  setTimeout(function(){
    // OK, finished jQuery staff, let's go redirect
    window.location.href = "/contact/";
  },500);
});
```

Imagine someone wrote a script/plugin with 10000 lines of code. With jQuery you can connect to this code with just a line or two.

Answer (score 82):

So, the question is how to make a redirect page, and not how to redirect to a website?

You only need to use JavaScript for this. Here is some tiny code that will create a dynamic redirect page.

```
<script>
    var url = window.location.search.split('url=')[1]; // Get the URL after ?url=
    if( url ) window.location.replace(url);
</script>
```

So say you just put this snippet into a `redirect/index.html` file on your website you can use it like so.

> `http://www.mywebsite.com/redirect?url=http://stackoverflow.com`

And if you go to that link it will automatically redirect you to **stackoverflow.com**.

> **[Link to Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location)**

**And that's how you make a *Simple* redirect page with JavaScript**

Edit:

There is also one thing to note. I have added `window.location.replace` in my code because I think it suits a redirect page, but, you must know that when using `window.location.replace` and you get redirected, when you press the back button in your browser it will **not** got back to the redirect page, and it will go back to the page before it, take a look at this little demo thing.

Example:

> The process: **store home** => **redirect page to google** => **google**
>
> When at google: **google** => **back button in browser** => **store home**

So, if this suits your needs then everything should be fine. If you want to include the redirect page in the browser history replace this

```
if( url ) window.location.replace(url);
```

with

```
if( url ) window.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 82):

You need to put this line in your code:

```
$(location).attr("href","http://stackoverflow.com");
```

If you don't have jQuery, go with JavaScript:

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
window.location.href("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Answer (score 79):

On your click function, just add:

```
window.location.href = "The URL where you want to redirect";
$('#id').click(function(){
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
});
```

Answer (score 65):

Try this:

```
location.assign("http://www.google.com");
```

[Code snippet of example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_loc_assign).

Answer (score 61):

jQuery is not needed. You can do this:

```
window.open("URL","_self","","")
```

It is that easy!

The best way to initiate an HTTP request is with `document.loacation.href.replace('URL')`.

Answer (score 59):

JavaScript is very extensive. If you want to jump to another page you have three options.

```
window.location.href='otherpage.com';
window.location.assign('otherpage.com');
//and...

window.location.replace('otherpage.com');
```

As you want to move to another page, you can use any from these if this is your requirement.
However all three options are limited to different situations. Chose wisely according to your requirement.

If you are interested in more knowledge about the concept, you can go through further.

```
window.location.href;     // Returns the href (URL) of the current page
window.location.hostname; // Returns the domain name of the web host
window.location.pathname; // Returns the path and filename of the current page
window.location.protocol; // Returns the web protocol used (http: or https:)
window.location.assign;   // Loads a new document
window.location.replace;  // Replace the current location with new one.
```

Answer (score 57):

## Using JavaScript:

#### Method 1:

```
window.location.href="http://google.com";
```

#### Method 2:

```
window.location.replace("http://google.com");
```

---

## Using jQuery:

#### Method 1: $(location)

```
$(location).attr('href', 'http://google.com');
```

#### Method 2: Reusable Function

```
jQuery.fn.redirectTo = function(url){
    window.location.href = url;
}

jQuery(window).redirectTo("http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 55):

First write properly. You want to navigate within an application for another link from your application for another link. Here is the code:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

And if you want to navigate pages within your application then I also have code, if you want.

Answer (score 55):

You can redirect in jQuery like this:

```
$(location).attr('href', 'http://yourPage.com/');
```

Answer (score 52):

> **First Way**

Here is the jQuery code for redirecting a page. Since, I have put this code on the $(document).ready() function, it will execute as soon as the page is loaded.

```js
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

You can even pass a URL directly to the **attr()** method, instead of using a variable.

> **Second Way**

```
 window.location.href="http://stackoverflow.com";
```

You can also code like this (both are same internally):

```
window.location="http://stackoverflow.com";
```

If you are curious about the difference between window.location and `window.location.href`, then you can see that the latter one is setting `href` property explicitly, while the former one does it implicitly. Since `window.location` returns an object, which by default sets its `.href` property.

> **Third Way**

There is another way to redirect a page using JavaScript, the `replace()` method of `window.location` object. You can pass a new URL to the `replace()` method, and it will simulate an HTTP redirect. By the way, remember that `window.location.replace()` method doesn't put the originating page in the session history, which may affect behavior of the back button. Sometime, it's what you want, so use it carefully.

```js
// Doesn't put originating page in history
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

> **Fourth Way**

The `location.assign()` method loads a new document in the browser window.

```
window.location.assign("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

The difference between `assign()` and `replace()` method is that the `location.replace()` method deletes the current URL from the document history, so it is unable to navigate back to the original document. You can't use the browsers **Back** button in this case. If you want to avoid this situation, you should use `location.assign()` method, because it loads a new Document in the browser.

> **Fifth Way**

like **attr()** method (after jQuery 1.6 introduce)

```js
var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
$(location).prop('href', url);
```

Answer (score 48):

In JavaScript and jQuery we can use the following code to redirect the one page to another page:

```
window.location.href="http://google.com";
window.location.replace("page1.html");
```

Answer (score 47):

Javascript:

```
window.location.href='www.your_url.com';
window.top.location.href='www.your_url.com';
window.location.replace('www.your_url.com');
```

Jquery:

```
var url='www.your_url.com';
$(location).attr('href',url);
$(location).prop('href',url);//instead of location you can use window
```

Answer (score 47):

## ECMAScript 6 + jQuery, 85 bytes

```
$({jQueryCode:(url)=>location.replace(url)}).attr("jQueryCode")("http://example.com")
```

Please don't kill me, this is a joke. It's a joke. *This is a joke.*

This did "provide an answer to the question", in the sense that it asked for a solution "using jQuery" which in this case entails forcing it into the equation somehow.

Ferrybig apparently needs the joke explained (still joking, I'm sure there are limited options on the review form), so without further ado:

Other answers are using jQuery's `attr()` on the `location` or `window` objects unnecessarily.

This answer also abuses it, but in a more ridiculous way. Instead of using it to set the location, this uses `attr()` to retrieve a function that sets the location.

The function is named `jQueryCode` even though there's nothing jQuery about it, and calling a function `somethingCode` is just horrible, especially when the something is not even a language.

The "85 bytes" is a reference to Code Golf. Golfing is obviously not something you should do outside of code golf, and furthermore this answer is clearly not actually golfed.

Basically, cringe.

Answer (score 46):

Here is a time-delay redirection. You can set the delay time to whatever you want:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Your Document Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function delayer(delay) {
            onLoad = setTimeout('window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/"', delay);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        delayer(8000)
    </script>
    <div>You will be redirected in 8 seconds!</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 44):

There are three main ways to do this,

```
window.location.href='blaah.com';
window.location.assign('blaah.com');
```

and...

```
window.location.replace('blaah.com');
```

The last one is best, for a traditional redirect, because it will not save the page you went to before being redirected in your search history. However, if you just want to open a tab with JavaScript, you can use any of the above.[1](http://basicuse.net/tips/pl/scripting_languages/javascript/how_to_make_a_page_redirect_in_javascript)

EDIT: The `window` prefix is optional.

Answer (score 44):

I just had to update this ridiculousness with yet another newer jQuery method:

```
var url = 'http://www.fiftywaystoleaveyourlocation.com';
$(location).prop('href', url);
```

Answer (score 38):

Write the below code after the PHP, HTML or jQuery section. If in the middle of the PHP or HTML section, then use the <script> tag.

```
location.href = "http://google.com"
```

Answer (score 33):

In **jQuery**, use `$(location).attr('href', url)`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwMKRevYa_M";
    $(location).attr('href', url); // Using this
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In *raw* **JavaScript**, there are a number of ways to achieve that:

```
window.location.href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwMKRevYa_M";
```

- sets href property explicitly.

```
window.location = "http://www.GameOfThrones.com";
```

- does it implicitly Since window.location returns an object, which by default sets its .href property.

```
window.location.replace("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

- replaces the location of the current window with the new one.

```
self.location = "http://www.somewebsite.com";
```

- sets the location of the current window itself.

Here is an example of JavaScript redirecting after a certain time (3 seconds):

```js
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "https://www.youtube.com/";
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 27):

In JavaScript and jQuery we use this following code to redirect the page:

```
window.location.href="http://google.com";
window.location.replace("page1.html");
```

But you can make a function in jQuery to redirect the page:

```
jQuery.fn.redirect=function(url)
{
    window.location.href=url;
}
```

And call this function:

```
jQuery(window).redirect("http://stackoverflow.com/")
```

Comment: Why are you passing `window` to the jQuery function in this line: `jQuery(window).redirect(...)`?

Comment: @A1rPun what i need to pass window ord document ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense as something that should be a jQuery method. There's no difference between `$("div").redirect(url)` and `$().redirect(url)`. You could make it a static method, like `$.redirect(url)` but there's not really much need for that either. jQuery doesn't need to be involved at all.

Answer (score 26):

Use the jQuery function:

```
$.extend({
  redirectPost: function(location, args) {
    var form = '';
    $.each(args, function(key, value) {
      form += '<input type="hidden" name="' + key + '" value="' + value + '">';
    });
    $('<form action="' + location + '" method="POST">' + form + '</form>').appendTo($(document.body)).submit();
  }
});
```

In your code you use it like this:

```
$.redirectPost("addPhotos.php", {pimreference:  $("#pimreference").val(), tag: $("#tag").val()});
```

Answer (score 24):

Simply in **JavaScript**, you can redirect to a specific page by using the following:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.test.com");
```

Or

```
location.replace("http://www.test.com");
```

Or

```
window.location.href = "http://www.test.com";
```

**Using jQuery:**

```
$(window).attr("location","http://www.test.com");
```

Answer (score 21):

You can use it like in the following code where `getRequestToForwardPage` is the request mapping ([URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator)). You can also use your URL.

```
function savePopUp(){
    $.blockUI();
    $.ajax({
        url:"GuestHouseProcessor?roomType="+$("#roomType").val(),
        data: $("#popForm").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        error: (function() {
            alert("Server Error");
            $.unblockUI();
    }),
    success: function(map) {
        $("#layer1").hide();
        $.unblockUI();
        window.location = "getRequestToForwardPage";
    }
});
```

This is for the same context of the application.

If you want to use only jquery specific code then following code may help:

```
 $(location).attr('href',"http://www.google.com");
 $jq(window).attr("location","http://www.google.com");
 $(location).prop('href',"http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 19):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "https://yourdomain.com";

// IE8 and lower fix
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s(?!9.0)/))
{
    var referLink = document.createElement("a");
    referLink.href = url;
    document.body.appendChild(referLink);
    referLink.click();
}

// All other browsers
else { window.location.replace(url); }
</script>
```

Answer (score 19):

Using `location.replace()` will redirect you, but without saving the history of the previous page. This is better to use when a form is submitted.

But when you want to keep your history you have to use `location.href=//path`.

**Examples:**

```
// Form with steps
document.getElementById('#next').onclick = function() {
   window.location.href='/step2' // Iteration of steps;
}

// Go to next step
document.getElementById('#back').onclick = function() {
   window.history.back();
}

// Finish
document.getElementById('#finish').onclick = function() {
   window.location.href = '/success';
}

// On success page
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       window.location.replace('/home'); // I can't go back to success page by pressing the back button
    },3000);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can write the Url.Action for the Button click event in the script section as follows.

```
function onclick() {
    location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Here is the code to redirect to some other page with a timeout of 10 seconds.

```
<script>
    function Redirect()
    {
        window.location="http://www.adarshkr.com";
    }

    document.write("You will be redirected to a new page in 10 seconds.");
    setTimeout('Redirect()', 10000);
</script>
```

You can also do it like this, on click of a button using location.assign:

```
<input type="button" value="Load new document" onclick="newPage()">
<script>
    function newPage() {
        window.location.assign("http://www.adarshkr.com")
    }
</script>
```

Comment: don't use inline click events. Bad practice and is not going to be supported in future iterations of all web browsers.

Answer (score 16):

This is very easy to implement. You can use:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";
```

This will remember the history of the previous page. So one can go back by clicking on the browser's back button.

Or:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/");
```

This method does not remember the history of the previous page. The back button becomes disabled in this case.

Answer (score 16):

If you prefer to use pure JavaScript I realized that using of `document.location.href = "https://example.com"` or `window.location.href = "https://example.com"` causes compatibility issues in Firefox. Instead try to use:

```js
location.href = "https://example.com";
location.replace("http://example.com");
```

In my case has solved the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/");
```

The `replace()` method does not save the originating page in the session history, so the user can't go back using the back button and again get redirected. NOTE: The browser back button will be deactivated in this case.

However, if you want an effect the same as clicking on a link you should go for:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/";
```

In this case, the browser back button will be active.

Answer (score 15):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(window.location.href === "http://stackoverflow.com") {      
         window.location.replace("https://www.google.co.in/");
       }
</script>
```

Answer (score 15):

**Single Page Application**, within the same application route

```
window.location.pathname = '/stack';
```

**JavaScript:**

```
location.href = "http://stack.com";
window.location = "http://stack.com";
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(location).attr('href', "http://www.stack.com");
$(window).attr('location', "http://www.stack.com");
```

**Angular 4**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
export class NavtabComponent{
    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }
    this.router.navigate(['bookings/taxi']);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Use:

```
function redirect(a) {
    location = a
}
```

And call it with: `redirect([url]);`

There's no need for the `href` after `location`, as it is implied.

Answer (score 14):

1. **location.assign():**

   To assign a route path by passing a path into it.. **Assign** will give you  a history even after the path was assigned.

   **Usage Method:** value should be passed into it.

   **For example:** `location.assign("http://google.com")`

   [image]
2. **location.href**

   Can define give a path into it... And it will redirect into a given path once it setup, and it will keep history...

   **Usage Method:** value should be assign into it.

   **For example:** `location.href = "http://google.com"`
3. **location.replace():**

   It will help to replace a path if you don't want to keep history. It won't give you a history once you replace its path.

   **Usage Method:** value should be pass into it.

   **For example:** `location.replace("http://google.com")`

   [image]

---

`assign()` and `href` are similar, and both can hold history. `assign` will work by passing a value and href works by assigning.

You can achieve it using JavaScript itself without using jQuery by assigning,

```
window.location = "http://google.com"
location.href = "http://google.com"
```

You can achieve similar thing using jQuery like below. It will do exactly the same like above,

```
$(window).attr('location', "http://www.google.com");
$(location).attr('href', "http://www.google.com");
```

You can easily understand the difference between both...

Here is the Location object,

[image: Location API from chrome]

Answer (score 13):

I just add another way:

To redirect for any specific page/links of your site to another page, just add this line of code:

```
<script>
    if(window.location.href == 'old_url')
    {
        window.location.href="new_url";
    }

    // Another URL redirect
    if(window.location.href == 'old_url2')
    {
        window.location.href="new_url2";
    }
</script>
```

For a real life example,

```
<script>
    if(window.location.href == 'https://old-site.com')
    {
        window.location.href="https://new-site.com";
    }

    // Another URL redirect
    if(window.location.href == 'https://old-site.com/simple-post.html')
    {
        window.location.href="https://new-site.com/simple-post.html";
    }
</script>
```

By using this simple code, you can redirect full site or any single page.

Answer (score 12):

You can redirect the page by using the below methods:

1. By using a meta tag in the head - `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://your-page-url.com" />`. Note that `content="0;`... is used for after how many seconds you need to redirect the page
2. By using JavaScript: `window.location.href = "http://your-page-url.com";`
3. By using jQuery: `$(location).attr('href', 'http://yourPage.com/');`

Comment: There is no reason to use jQuery for this and `window.` is unnecessary.

Comment: Where i have used window. in jquery Query Example ?  ... if you want to redirect the page through javascript ... than you need to use window.location..

Comment: I meant those as separate things: you shouldn't use jQuery for this, and in the JavaScript example, you can simplify `window.location.href =` to `location.href =` or even `location =`.

Comment: Yes location.href = would be better option to redirect the page -:)

Answer (score 10):

I already use the function redirect() of JavaScript. It's working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //It's similar to HTTP redirect
        window.location.replace("http://www.Technomark.in");

        //It's similar to clicking on a link
        window.location.href = "Http://www.Technomark.in";
    })
</script>
```

Comment: what is the difference between this answer and the first ?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to redirect to a route within the same app simply

```
window.location.pathname = '/examplepath'
```

would be the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

All way to make a redirect from the client side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript and jQuery example to redirect a page or URL </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="redirect">
            <h2>Redirecting to another page</h2>
        </div>

        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            // JavaScript code to redirect a URL
            window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
            // window.location.replace('http://code.shouttoday.com');

            // Another way to redirect page using JavaScript

            // window.location.assign('http://code.shouttoday.com');
            // window.location.href = 'http://code.shouttoday.com';
            // document.location.href = '/relativePath';

            //jQuery code to redirect a page or URL
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //var url = "http://code.shouttoday.com";
                //$(location).attr('href',url);
                // $(window).attr('location',url)
                //$(location).prop('href', url)
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

**Redirecting User using jQuery/JavaScript**

By using the location object in jQuery or JavaScript we can redirect the user to another web page.

**In jQuery**

The code to redirect the user from one page to another is:

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com';
$(location).attr('href', url);
```

**In JavaScript**

The code to redirect the user from one page to another is:

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com';
window.location.href = url;
```

**Or**

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com';
window.location = url;
```

Answer (score 6):

In my work experience, JavaScript is much better to redirect.

It depends on how you want to change the location. If you want to log your website in users history, use `window.location.href='ur website';`. Otherwise to do it without logging in history, use `window.location.replace("your website");`.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I use it.

```
   window.location.replace('yourPage.aspx');   
   // If you're on root and redirection page is also on the root

   window.location.replace(window.location.host + '/subDirectory/yourPage.aspx');

   // If you're in sub directory and redirection page is also in some other sub directory.
```

Comment: @Phil you ever came across sub directories in you application suppose if you're on http://www.url.com/admin/login.aspx you want to go to http://www.url.com/customer/orders.aspx  window.location.host will give you http://www.url.com then you can append your sub directory and page