# jQuery - Create link element and click it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically generate a link to Post a tweet on twitter and then click on it like this...

```
$("body").prepend("<a id=\"twitter_link\" href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet'></a>");

$( "#twitter_link" ).click(function() {
  console.log( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

This is not working, where am i going wrong?

Comment: Function execution context? Possibly? `prepend` is an async operation so I guess the handler is getting attached *before* the actual element is rendered?

Comment: @weirdpanda I don't think prepend is async...

Comment: @mpen, yeah. Just read it. My fault. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is 99% done!

## Your new `a` element doesn't have text

## Important

> The click event it's necessary if you need to execute a logic when the new link is clicked, otherwise, that event it's unnecessary.

```js
$("body").prepend("<a id=\"twitter_link\" href='https://twitter.com/intent/tweet'>Hello World</a>");

$( "#twitter_link" ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //This is just to show your logic is working!
  console.log( "Handler for .click() called." );  
  location.href = this.href; //This is to redirect to the specific page after any previous executed logic.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Resource

- [What's the best way to automatically redirect someone to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200337/whats-the-best-way-to-automatically-redirect-someone-to-another-webpage)

Comment: Although the log fires, the link doesn't open

Comment: @fightstarr20 the `e.preventDefault()` is just to show your logic is working.

Comment: @fightstarr20 I don't understand, you want to execute a logic when the new link is clicked?

Comment: Exactly, I am inserting some custom tweet text when a button is clicked.  I want to then click the link so the person doesn't have to click again

Answer (score 1):

you can also try creating the element first, adding the event listener and then appending to the body

```
var $a = $("<a id=\"twitter_link\" href='#'>test</a>" );

$a.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log( "Handler for .click() called." );
});

$("body").prepend($a);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to automatically click the link, you have to call `.click()` on the element -- you're binding a click handler. Here's an example without jQuery adapted from a project I'm working on:

```js
function clickLink(url) {
    let anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = url;
    document.body.appendChild(anchor); // Firefox requires us to actually insert the element into the DOM before we can click it
    anchor.click();
    document.body.removeChild(anchor);
}

clickLink('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

Watch your devtools console though, because if you try linking to another domain you might get this error:

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=--R8WpqeLpTM8AeZoYbgAg' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.