# Redirecting automatically to another site in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mobile

I have a website, with both mobile and desktop versions. But I would like to somehow connect them where the desktop site is the default landing page. So, if the viewport's width is smaller than 600px (for example), it automatically redirects to the mobile site (that is uploaded with a different domain). I am using React, so solutions using react would work as well. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to automatically redirect someone to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200337/whats-the-best-way-to-automatically-redirect-someone-to-another-webpage)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: I have tried window.location.replace, but it just adds to the domain I'm on. For instance, if I am on google.com and I redirect to facebook.com, it just redirects to "google.com/facebook.com"

Answer (score 2):

```
// use this to avoid redirects when a user clicks "back" in their browser
window.location.replace('http://somewhereelse.com');

// use this to redirect, a back button call will trigger the redirection again
window.location.href = "http://somewhereelse.com";
```

Already answered by Owen in this Question:
[What's the best way to automatically redirect someone to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200337/whats-the-best-way-to-automatically-redirect-someone-to-another-webpage)